# How can I compute the gradient w.r.t. a non-variable in TensorFlow's eager execution mode?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to compute the gradient of my model's loss with respect to its input in order to create an adversarial example. Since the model's input is non-trainable, I need to compute the gradient with respect to a tensor, not a variable. However, I found that TensorFlow's `GradientTape` returns `None` gradients if the tensor is not a trainable variable:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

a = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([1., 2., 3.]), dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant([1., 2., 3.])
c = tf.Variable([1., 2., 3.], trainable=False)
d = tf.Variable([1., 2., 3.], trainable=True)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    result = a + b + c + d

grads = tape.gradient(result, [a, b, c, d])
```

`print(grads)` prints:

```
[None, None, None, <tf.Tensor: id=26, shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32)>]
```

I went through TensorFlow's [Eager Execution tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/eager_basics) and the [Eager Execution guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager), but couldn't find a solution for calculating the gradient w.r.t. a tensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`tf.GradientTape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) documentation reveals the simple solution:

> Trainable variables (created by `tf.Variable` or `tf.get_variable`, where `trainable=True` is default in both cases) are automatically watched. Tensors can be manually watched by invoking the `watch` method on this context manager.

In this case,

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(a)
    tape.watch(b)
    tape.watch(c)
    result = a + b + c + d

grads = tape.gradient(result, [a, b, c, d])
```

will result in `print(grads)`:

```
[<tf.Tensor: id=26, shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32)>, 
 <tf.Tensor: id=26, shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32)>, 
 <tf.Tensor: id=26, shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32)>, 
 <tf.Tensor: id=26, shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32)>]
```